# Multithreaded Powershell GUI Application never displays when called from CMD.exe

Tags: windows, multithreading, powershell

I have finally finished my powershell wpf application for internal use at my company, and it runs as expected when called from a powershell window, however when I try to call it from CMD, or from Visual Studio as an external tool, the GUI window never shows up.

My application functions very closely to [this write up](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/), with a few changes to the display and functions that run in the background.

Can anyone explain why my ps1 file does not display the gui when I call it from CMD, but it does when called from the powershell command window? Here is the gist of the script:

```
$Global:syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
    [xml]$xaml = @"
<valid wpf>
"@
    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)

    $syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

    [xml]$XAML = $xaml
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | %{
        #Find all of the form types and add them as members to the synchash
        $syncHash.Add($_.Name,$syncHash.Window.FindName($_.Name) )
    }

    ## Custom functions for items in syncHash here ##

    $syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $syncHash.Error = $Error
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$date = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

I am calling this script in cmd.exe "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\pathToFile\file.ps1"

My Execution policy has been updated so that I can run scripts as well.

Comment: You need to provide the details of how you are running your script in both cases. Be specific and detailed. (Remember, nobody can see your screen. You don't want people to guess.)

Comment: Edited.  I had to take out some stuff since it is something for work, but this is the main portion of the script that does not seem to be functioning

Comment: I think Bill_Stewart meant we need details of how it is being launched. What are you actually typing at the command prompt? Or at least that is what I would like to know.

Comment: You can't call a powershell script directly like `.\folder\script.ps1` instead from the command prompt call the PowerShell executable with the script path as an argument:

`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe H:\Scripts\folder\script.ps1`

Comment: I updated my question to reflect how I am calling it.  I am calling powershell.exe and then the path to my script

Comment: Does it work if you run the command from cmd.exe like so: `powershell -nop -ep bypass -c "& { . C:\pathToFile\file.ps1 }"` ?

Comment: @C.Helling No, it doesn't.  It just thinks for a minute and then goes to a new cmd line.  No output whatsoever

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon Sorry, what is the command that you're using to run it from powershell?

Comment: @C.Helling From the powershell command window, I just have to call pathToFile\File.ps1

Comment: I can't see why the command I posted wouldn't work, aside from proper use of quotation marks. Something like this perhaps?: `powershell -nop -ep bypass -c "&  . ""C:\pathToFile\file.ps1"""` ?

Comment: I call all my WPF GUIs simply like this : `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\scripts\file.ps1"` even those who are multi-threaded with runspaces

Comment: @C.Helling Neither of these suggestions work.  For some reason, it still doesn't display anything

Comment: Can you instead try running a script that saves a file.txt to the desktop instead, and call it the same way you are now, to see if the problem is with the script or how you are calling it?

Comment: @C.Helling Just tried that with a simple
`$text | Set-Content 'file.txt'`
and it worked just fine calling it from cmd like I have tried calling my WPF Gui application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, I got it figured out.  For some reason I needed to run the command with the NoExit option

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File "pathToFile\File.ps1"
```